# How to add data into HTML table irrespective of number of elements in array

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, html-table

I am trying to display the array data into HTML table but table design or structure should be untouched **irrespective of number of elements in array**.

I tried some of logic like looping, but table structure changes.I don't want that.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
    $goods=["ABC","XYZ","PQR","DEF"];
    $qty=[12345,25120,14521,12541];
    $rate=[12.00,13.02,15.00,14.00];
    ?>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Goods Description</th>
        <th>Total Quantity(pcs)</th>
        <th>Rate per unit(Rs.)</th>
        <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
      </tr>
 <?php
     for($i=0;$i<count($goods);$i++) {
     ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $goods[$i];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $qty[$i];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rate[$i];?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total Value</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Frieght</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total Taxable Value</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tax</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>tax</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>tax</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total Tax Amount</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Grand Total Tax Amount</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Expected Output:
[Expected_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpV2H.png)

Comment: What? Maybe I'm dumb but I don't see what you are trying to do. Have you looked at for loop or foreach?

Comment: If you have tried a loop then post that code. It's not fun to start from scratch just because you don't want to share the code

Comment: I have added the Loop code, it changes the table structure.

Comment: Something wrong with my answer?

Comment: No. Its Perfect.I knew how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: So can you accept the answer?

Comment: accepting answers is part of SO. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need. You had not included the words in the loop.
It was insanely hard to write this code on the phone so there may be something left out.

```
$goods=["ABC","XYZ","PQR","DEF"];
$qty=[12345,25120,14521,12541];
$rate=[12.00,13.02,15.00,14.00];
$words=["Total Value", "Frieght", "Total Taxable Value", "Tax", "Tax", "Tax", "Total Tax Amount"]; 
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr No.</th>
    <th>Goods Description</th>
    <th>Total Quantity(pcs)</th>
    <th>Rate per unit(Rs.)</th>
    <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
  </tr>
 <?php
 for ($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++) {
 ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i+1 . "."; ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($goods[$i])) echo $goods[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($qty[$i])) echo $qty[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($rate[$i])) echo $rate[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $words[$i];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

https://3v4l.org/f1BnW. 
Edit forgot number on first column.